# Recommendations for running Magento on Azure websites with ClearDB Database

Tags: magento, azure, cleardb

I've set up a shop in Magento using Azure web apps but it's running very slow at the moment. I've scaled to the standard pricing tier and turned on autoscale but it's still very slow. Could it be the database that is the problem? I only have the free Mercury plan and I still need to upgrade for more space so I will do that.

Anyone running Magento on Azure web apps with ClearDB that have recommendations for good performance? It´s not a very big site, only about 40 products.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I would possible suggest creating a VM in Azure (same region) and hosting a DB on there... That is what we do and while pricier it is very good at doing what it should.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend upgrading the the ClearDB from the Mercury plan. I am confident that is your bottleneck.

Magento is a very db intensive application and the free (Mercury) tier is for very basic performance and small apps such as small wordpress blogs.

Try upgrading to the Venus or Saturn plan and should see tremendous improvement in performance.

Another option is that you could setup your own Linux VM and install MySQL, Apache, etc and then scale up from there. if you are comfortable doing that it will give you some more control.